# Building empty ASP.NET project in MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio) generates "Unexpected binary element: 0" error

Tags: asp.net, .net, xamarin, mono, monodevelop

I've installed the latest versions of Mono and MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio) onto a box with the latest Windows 8.1. When I create a project with even the "Empty ASP.NET" template, any sort of build or clean operation fails with the error, "Unexpected binary element: 0". Web searching is not turning up anything recent, or helpful.

Is there a known issue here, or something that I might be missing?  I haven't even started to write any custom code... I'm just working with a fresh project that Xamarin Studio's own "new solution" wizard setup for me.  I understand that Mono can have compatibility issues with ASP.NET code in the wild, but it seems bizarre that even something this basic and built-in wouldn't run out of the box.

NOTE: I'm experiencing the same problem whether Xamarin Studio is configured to use Mono or proprietary .NET under "Tools -> Options".  I've also seen the same result on two different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally seen this using parallel mono installs on OS-X and there is an outstanding bug report concerning it. The original bug issuer was not using a parallel mono install, but was using one of the older Mono versions install by the default installer but they were also on OS-X, so it seems it is not OS-X dependent.

[Bug 29958 - Mono 4.0 - Causing 'Unexpected binary element: 0' build failure when compiling against previous mono version](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29958)

Please add your finding to that open bug report.

**Workaround:**

The only work around I have found is to turn off MSBuild in the project, not a great workaround at all depending on how your solution/projects are configured but something you can try.

Comment: Where are you seeing the option to disable MSBuild?  I'm using Xamarin Studio 5.9.4 on Windows... I'm not sure if things are different in that environment vs. the "MonoDevelop"-branded binaries on OS X or Linux.

Comment: I'm running the same XS version. Open up the Project options / Build / General  its the second option down under the Target Framework option

Comment: Ahh... I was right-clicking at the solution-level rather than the project-level.  I see the dialog you're talking about, but the second option down refers to the project's "main class".  It looks like XS may be treating this ASP.NET project as a DLL project?!?  I'm not sure what to make of that... I just generated an "Empty ASP.NET" app using the wizard, and did nothing else to alter it in any way.

Comment: Yes, an Asp.net project would be a library. I'll check my Windows box later about the MSBuild option(?), basically the non-MSBuild option creates the mcs compiler arguments and calls/shells to it...

Comment: For giggles, I installed an Ubuntu environment on a VirtualBox VM... and the dialog there looks exactly the same as the Windows screenshot I linked above.  On the other hand, the "Empty ASP.NET" application does successfully build on Linux.

Comment: Are you working with an older version of MonoDevelop / XS?  I haven't been able to track down a "Disable MSBuild..." on any platform.  All I've found is a reference too it in the release notes for an older 4.x version two years ago.

Comment: I'm absolutely dumbfounded here.  I've installed the current version on both Windows 8.1 and on Ubuntu Linux (not using Ubunut's repos, but instead registering Xamarin's APT repo).  I haven't done anything custom at all, and yet that checkbox simply isn't there on either environment.  Do you have an "msbuild.exe' in your PATH or something when you run MonoDevelop / XS?  I just don't understand what could possibly be different about ALL of my machines that would make me the only person on earth seeing this issue on every clean install.

Comment: Hey, are you sure you're working an "Empty ASP.NET" project like I am?  I find that the MSBuild checkbox IS there when I create a console app project...

Comment: Your right, I'm using modified asp templates as I do not use XSP to debug, I attach to a fast-cgi process via nginx. I re-created using the Empty ASP.net project and do not get the ""Unexpected binary element: 0" like you are, but I still get that error on using parallel mono installs or the older mono versions that are installed via the default installer. I have not idea what is causing it, need to buckle down and trace it in a MonoDevelop install vs Xamarin Studio

Comment: Interesting.  On Windows, it's the default behavior for ASP.NET apps with the lastest versions of everything installed (does ANYONE run XS on Windows?!?).  I can't really blame the underlying Mono version, because I see the same behavior whether "Tools->Options" has set the .NET Runtime to Mono or proprietary .NET.